# Design breaks in android default browser only

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I have a div inside a div its design breaks when i view it in android default browser, Can't it as i dont have tools to see what is causing this. Rest it works well on all browsers.

```
<div class="row">                
    <h2 >PRAYER </h2>
    <div class="time-wrapper">
        <div class="pt-circle">
            <div class="pt-time">
                <b>Fajr</b><br> 
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblFajrTime">04:58</span>
            </div>
        </div>                  
        <div class="pt-circle">
            <div class="pt-time">
                 <b>Dhur</b><br>
                 <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDhurTime">12:08</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-circle">
            <div class="pt-time">
                <b>Asr</b><br>
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblAsrTime">15:28</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-circle">
            <div class="pt-time">
                <b>Magrib</b><br>
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMagribTime">17:52</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-circle">
            <div class="pt-time">
                 <b>Isha</b><br>
                 <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIshaTime">19:22</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`<div class="pt-time">` div should be aligned in center vertically and horizontally.

[image]
[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdyQwo?editors=100)

Answer (score 0):

SOlution

```
.pt-time{position: relative;  padding:0; margin:0; top: 25%;  text-align:center; }
```

I removed transform: `translateY(-50%);`  and changed top:25%;

`translateY(-50%);` should have not been there.